# How to initiate azure replication twice a day at certain time

Tags: ubuntu, azure, replication

I have a scenario where I want to replicate my Azure VMs. I want to initiate them twice a day and at a certain time, i.e, Morning 6 and evening 6. My VMs are Ubuntu.

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.